# How do I mock Mongoose's "lean()" query with Jest and NestJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I have a Person entity with its own Repository class, which I want to test. This repository class injects the Mongoose model as suggested in the docs of NestJS, like so:

```js
    @InjectModel(Person.name)
    private model: Model<PersonModel>
```

And the code I'm trying to test is a query similar to `const res = await this.model.find().lean();`

My issue, though, is when it comes to testing the lean() query, as it's a chained function to find() methods. I was able to get as far as I could, but when it comes to mocking it I am having some type conflicts:

```js
const modelMockObject = {
  find: jest.fn(),
  findOne: jest.fn(),
  findOneAndUpdate: jest.fn(),
  updateOne: jest.fn(),
};

// ...

  let MockPersonModel: Model<PersonModel>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockModule: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ...,
        {
          provide: getModelToken(Person.name),
          useValue: modelMockObject,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    MockPersonModel = mockModule.get<Model<PersonModel>>(
      Person.name,
    );
  }); 

// ...
// Inside a describe/it test...

      const personModel = new MockPersonModel({
        name: 'etc'
      });

      jest.spyOn(MockPersonModel, 'findOne').mockReturnValueOnce({
        lean: () => ({ exec: async () => personModel }),
      });
```

The error the linter informs on `personModel` (second-last line) is the following:

```
Type 'Promise<PersonModel>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<P>'.
  Type 'PersonModel' is not assignable to type 'P'.
    'P' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'PersonModel'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2100, 5): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe too late for you, but for the next one who search to solve this problem like me too.

You can simply use **mockImplementation**:
eg:

```js
MockPersonModel.findOne.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
    lean: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(personModel),
}));
```

You can check here for more detail about this implementation:

[my simple test](http://You%20can%20check%20here%20my%20simple%20implementation:%20%20https://github.com/tienduy-nguyen/bookstore/blob/master/server/src/modules/book/test/book.service.spec.ts)